# checkPropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.checkPropTypes is no longer supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I have these three warnings in my app when I'm using a version higher than the 15.0.0 of react.......

[warning in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzCwp.png)
[warning on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paDCD.png)

I don't see how I can fix this?
I tried to do: **`npm install --save prop-types`** but it doesn't change anything..........
In this state are these warnings important?

here is a copy of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mobileMM",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "eslint": "^4.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "flow-bin": "0.49.1",
    "jest-expo": "^21.0.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^21.0.3",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.4",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^4.13.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.23",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.19"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should import `checkPropTypes` from prop-types package.

Comment: ok thx but i don't use this in my component for the moment (i have edit my post with a copy of my package.json)

Comment: That's because one of your dependencies uses the old PropTypes API. Those warnings are only important if you want to update to react 16

Comment: A good way to track these types of issues down is turn on Remote Debugging. In the dev console (likely in the chrome page that opened) you will see the warning. You should be able to expand it to see the stack trace. Start at the top and work your way down through it until you encounter what is likely one of your dependencies. That dependency either needs to be updated or a PR submitted to switch to using `prop-types`

Comment: @Fabio Antunes Thank you for your advice and your feedback.

Comment: @mevans9 thx , that seems like a good way to track down the dependency in question